# editing fonts of category links from the_category() funtion

Tags: categories, theme-development, themes, pages

I have multiple pages using `content-featured.php` I'm having trouble pasting the code.. that file uses `the_category` function

`The_category` function displays names/links of categories. I'm having extreme difficulty editing the type of font for these category links. I was told to open the source for the page that uses this, look at the body class for the `template-specific` class it uses which is `page-Id-2`. And use that with custom css like `.page-I'd-2 .entry-title { font-family: somefont; }`.

However that didn't work.

Is there any more info needed here to help me with this issue?  Again I need to edit the fonts for category links displayed by the `the_category()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `the_category()` (so without passing parameters), the result will be something like:

```
<ul class='post-categories'>
<li><a href="../cat1">Category 1</a><li>
<li><a href="../cat2">Category 2</a><li>
</ul>
```

So a css line like `.post-categories li a {font-family:Myfont;}` should do it.

Reference: `the_category()` calls [`get_the_category_list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/), which does the actual output. This function ends with a filter, which you could use to assign further classes, even to individual links.

Comment: Ok thank you , I will try that when I get home. Yes I was looking a previous questions how the_category works... very interesting.    At one point I cracked and simply put a font face around the the_category in the php file, and someone told me that's the wrong way to do it. Any reason why? It worked though

Comment: The idea is to have all your design stuff in one file so if you want to change your design you don't have to go through all templates hunting down where you assigned that font.

Comment: OK I totally get it now. And that there is no specific rules that would penalize me an SEo for doing it that way? Because considering the fact that I got so many answers from experts and none of them worked up just in case your answer doesn't work I might just go ahead and wrap the font face around it ha ha work too long on the stupid issue

Comment: Nobody knows exactly what Google looks for to rank pages. Surely your css  is not a major factor. Anyway, the main reason to do things by the book should not be SEO, but your own ease for future development.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll reply back if it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, CJBJ thank you. It worked out well.  That was cool thanks.  May I bug you for couple more questions?  1. Can I hire you to fix upcoming issues on my site? 2. would this CSS code affect just what is output from the_category or will it affect all category links?

Comment: If the answer solves your question, please mark it as 'solved' by clicking the chechmark. In this way the system registers the solution and this question won't pop up later as 'needs attention'.

Comment: Now regarding your questions. Sorry, I'm not for hire for simple design stuff. You're probably better off by finding a local wp-designer (also, css fairly easy to learn). If you place the code in your `style.css`it will affect only output of `the_category`, but that function might be called in other places in your theme as well.

Comment: Excuse the noob questions.  The" ⭐️ " under the up down arrows .  That's what you mean by checkmark? Because I can't see any actual check marks . I'm on iOS mobile lol. I'm trying to accept this